# Concatenation of data does not occur?

Tags: jquery

**Strange situation, I can not concatenate 2 lines in JQuery:**

```
block_header_audience.html("Text " + groups_info[group_block_id - 1].groupName.toUpperCase());
```

**Where:**

```
block_header_audience - selector

groups_info[] - object

groups_info[group_block_id - 1].groupName.toUpperCase() = 'VALUE'
```

As a result, I have only leaves the string "VALUE", "Text " is not attached to the string.

How do I fix this situation?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with the exact case?

Comment: He has, it's in the top line next to "Text "

Comment: ... "Text" + groups...

Comment: Do not assign value to a return value (ie' `toUpperCase() = 'VALUE'`) or is it just debugger output?

Comment: console.log(groups_info[group_block_id - 1].groupName.toUpperCase());

Comment: Guys, the second code block is him explaining what each of the types are, not his actual code.

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: @MartinEston: Can you log the concatenated string, or assign it to a variable and then log that?

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rvoumya9/

Comment: console.log(groups_info[group_block_id - 1].groupName.toUpperCase());

[span.audience-block-header.col-lg-10, span.audience-block-header.col-.........., constructor: function…]

Comment: If I correct understand it's not a text, it's a selector. But how can I get text...?